# Win 7 size within VMWare

Tags: macos, windows, settings, vmware

I use VMWare with a Win 7 virtual machine.

I have a late 2012 iMac with 20GB of RAM. I use Windows for ...

- running Groupwise constantly
- using Respondus occasionally
- Explorer (please don't judge--I have to test Blackboard LMS occasionally) 
   :-)

What is the appropriate size for it to run in?

Comment: Since VMWare can add disk and RAM space on the fly, why not start with as small as can run and only give the VM more when you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with VMWare fusion's defaults for Windows 7:

- 60 GB drive
- 1 GB RAM

Unless the memory on the guest OS becomes very constrained, you might only need to bump it to 2 GB to get a little speed up if needed. The 2012 iMac CPU is quite capable and you do have significant amounts of RAM so you could juice the VM to a lot more RAM if needed without starving OS X for memory.